# flask application cannot run with python command

Tags: python, flask

I am new to web service development. I started with Flask. In many tutorials, I have seen running the flask application file(the file that holds the Flask instance) with python command and at first, I also did it but now for some reason, the file cannot be run with `python [file_name].py` command. However, if I run with `flask run`, then it works.

Can anyone tell me what might have gone wrong. Here is my project structure-

TaskManager-
     app.py
     venv [virtual environment]
     **pycache**

When I do flask run, I get following-

```
(venv) XYZ-MBP:TaskManager xyz$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and my app.py file looks like-

```
from flask import Flask

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def api():
    return "Hello world"

if __name__ == "main":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I do-

```
python app.py
```

the server doesn't run. It simply doesn't do anything, no error msg, nothing and shows like-

```
(venv) XYZ-MBP:TaskManager xyz$ python app.py
(venv) XYZ-MBP:TaskManager xyz$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change if statement as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`__name__` variable equals `'__main__'` not `'main'` when file is executed directly (your module is the main program).

Comment: Thank you, that was very silly. However, I am confused now as why it would run with flask run command?

Comment: It's because `flask run` command runs development server by default if it is told where to find the application. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using py instead of python ,

py api.py